# Why is "Good Friday" called "good", instead of sad or bad?

Tags: meaning, phrases

This Friday (Good Friday, April 22) is a day of sadness to the human kind. Then, why is it called *Good Friday*?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Friday

Comment: I don't think this question is for EL&U. Not everyone considers Good Friday a sad day. In fact some Christians argue for its *goodness* in the literal sense of the word, because Christ's death, even though a *sad* event, was necessary for all the good things to follow.

Comment: Leave it Jimi Oke. I just asked :)

Comment: Jimi raises a good point though. The premise of your question is wrong if it is not a day of sadness.

Comment: Plus, @Rauf, it is most certainly not something-or-other "to the human kind." It is a special day - be it good, sad, bad, or whatever - to the adherents of a particular religion to which *some* of humankind subscribes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Wikipedia page on [Good Friday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Friday) reports the following:

> from the now obsolete senses *pious*, *holy* of the word "good."

So, *good* can be traced back to meaning holy, which then gives more sense to the expression.

Comment: This is all general reference. But what I don't understand is why it has become, de facto, "Good Friday" in that sense, rather than  "Holy Friday". What is it about the word "Good" that made it the word of choice *at the time*, rather than "Holy" or "Pious", for instance? Were these words that interchangeable at the time? Etymological roots in this case leave me unsatisfied. Is there more to this?

Answer (score 0):

The obsolete sense of "good" may explain the origin of the name "Good Friday". The fact that the name has endured reflects the view of many Christians that Jesus Christ's death brings great benefits, consistent with the teaching of Jesus himself as recorded in the Bible.

Comment: Interestingly, the day before Good Friday is called Maundy Thursday.  Maundy, according to the AHD, is "[f]rom Middle English maunde, ceremony of washing the feet of the poor on this day, from Old French mande, from Latin (novum) mand³tum, (new) commandment (from Jesus's words to the Apostles after washing their feet, John 13:34)."  Jesus washed his disciples' feet shortly before he was crucified.  He was demonstrating some of the GOOD which would come out of his self-sacrifice on Good Friday; namely, Christian servant-leaders who, like their Master, put others' needs above their own.